# python & json - how to add objects to objects

Tags: python, json

`{"something": {}}`

how do I add another object inside "something" like

`{"something": {"something2": "as"}}`

I tried `append()` and `update()` but those didn't work. I also want to add as many arrays and objects as I can

Comment: You don't have arrays, you have objects. Or, in Python terms, you don't have lists, you have dicts. Either way, that's why `append` isn't going to work. `update` would work if you did it right, but you don't need it; just do `thing['something']['something2'] = 'as'`.

Comment: If first one is called `initial_json` then, may be you could try: `initial_json['something'].update({"something2": "as"})`

Comment: Maybe some more context on what you're trying to do would be nice? :)

Answer (score 0):

The task is qed using `pip install jq`:

```
import json;
from jq import jq;

s='{"something": {}}';

data=json.loads(s);

answer=jq('.something = {"something2": "as"}').transform(data);

print(answer);
```